# Argument type '()' does not conform to expected type 'View' SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, swiftui

I am trying to create a startup screen then animate to the mainMenu, but I get the error specified in the title. You can probably see how I am trying to do this. Please help.

```
struct Content: View {
    @State var ShowMainMenu = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if (ShowMainMenu) {
                MainMenu()
            } else {
                ContentView(ToMainMenu: $ShowMainMenu)
            }
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var ToMainMenu:Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("I hate phone numbers")
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+1.5) {
                withAnimation {
                    self.ToMainMenu.toggle()
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: @matt MainMenu is just another view and by the way, what MainMenu shows is irrelevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot execute code in a `view` but you could execute something in `onAppear` of that `view`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var ShowMainMenu = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if (ShowMainMenu) {
                Text("Hello")
            } else {
                Content(ToMainMenu: $ShowMainMenu)
            }
        }
    }
}
struct Content: View {
    @Binding var ToMainMenu: Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("I hate phone numbers")
        }.onAppear() {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+1.5) {
                withAnimation {
                    self.ToMainMenu.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I had to change the names of `Content` and `ContentView`

I hope this helps.

Comment: WOW! THANK YOU THANK YOU